# Can I create "attributed" types in C++?

Tags: c++, c++14

When I say "attribute", I mean something along the lines of `std:array<int, 5> arr`. The `5` is an attribute of the array.

Here's a motivating example: suppose I want to create a number or string that contains formatting information. So I might like to be able to write `Double<7,2> foo`, meaning that I want foo to be a double, and when I print it, it is to have width 7, and precision 2. I can make assignments in the usual way:

```
foo = 42;
double bar = foo;
```

Is there a way to do this?

You might be asking why I want to do it this way. Why not, for example, define a class that takes width and precision in its constructor? The answer is that I don't think you can use them in structures. For example, I want to be able to do something like:

```
struct Account {
    std::string description;
    Double<7, 2> amount;
    Double<7, 2> balance;
    Double<9, 3> percent;
};
```

Comment: Are you asking about [non-type template parameters](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters#Non-type_template_parameter)?

Comment: `5` is a *template parameter*. The concept already has a name :-)

Comment: `template <int M, int N> struct Double{};`, an overload for assignment, and suitable conversion operators will allow to you use `Double` in the way you have it in the question.

Comment: Is there a need to persist these values with required precision? Why not simply adjust the precision/representation at the time it is required to have that precision? i.e. when you output/display the value, or perform a calculation on it.

Comment: @Joachim, Kerrek: yes, I think non-type template parameters is what I'm looking for. It's something I'm trying to wrap my head around it at the moment.

Comment: @Bathsheba: I think it is a good idea to persist the values, as I consider them to be fixed. I know what I want them to be at compile time. It also allows me to do something like `typedef Double<7, 2> Currency;`

Comment: You'll find many examples with this general idea for the implementation of fixed-point math in C++.  See for example: https://gist.github.com/dflemstr/294959.

Comment: On StackOverflow Documentation [Non-type template parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%2b%2b/460/templates/16713/non-type-template-parameter#t=201609261328102698616)

Answer (score 3):

You can write your own wrapper class with Non-type template parameters and `double` implicit conversion. The advantage is that the size of such class remains the same.

```
#include <iostream>

template<std::streamsize WIDTH, std::streamsize PRECISION>
struct DoubleEx
{
    double value;

    DoubleEx(double fValue) : value(fValue) {}

    operator double() const { return value; }

    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& stream, const DoubleEx &val)
    {
        stream.width(WIDTH);
        auto oldPrecision = stream.precision();
        stream.precision(PRECISION);
        stream << val.value;
        stream.precision(oldPrecision);
        return stream;
    }
};

int main()
{
    DoubleEx<15, 8> num1 = 123.45678;
    double num2 = num1;
    auto num3 = num1;


    std::cout << "num1 = " << num1 << "  size=" << sizeof(num1) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "num2 = " << num2 << "  size=" << sizeof(num2) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "num3 = " << num3 << "  size=" << sizeof(num3) << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
num1 =       123.45678  size=8
num2 = 123.457  size=8
num3 =       123.45678  size=8
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I got what you mean, but maybe mixins can help you.
As a minimal, working example:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <string>

template<std::size_t N, std::size_t M>
struct Double {
    operator double() { return N*M; }
};

struct Description {
    std::string description;
};

template<typename ...T>
struct Mock: T... { };

using Account = Mock<Double<7, 2>, Description>;

int main() {
    Account account;
    account.description = "foo";
    double d = account;
}
```